# I'm trying to install NumPy into VS Code and it gives me a syntax error

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

"I am typing into the terminal "pip install numpy" and I get back "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Is there something I should be doing before hand to get this to work?

[VS Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzsAh.png)

I'm not sure exactly what I should be doing to get it to work. I am very new to programming in general."

For anyone else that has this issue in the future: I was putting this into the python terminal instead of the terminal called "powershell"

Also you may have to install pip first

Comment: Do you have python and pip installed? If so, you need to add them to your PATH so they can be found.

Comment: That's a console command meant to be run in the command prompt or terminal. It's not Python code. You're trying to run `pip install numpy` as if that is valid Python code. Which it is not.

Comment: I'm putting it into the terminal titled "powershell" and now its telling me that pip isnt recognized. I'm assuming i have to install it? I guess its time to figure that out!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the python interactive terminal instead of the shell terminal. In the python interactive terminal, you can directly enter the python code and press Enter to run. But the `pip` command needs to be executed in a shell terminal.

You can use `Ctrl+Z` or `exit()` to exit the current interactive terminal, and then use the `pip install numpy` to install the package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are actually typing `pip install numpy` as a Python code. You should first exit the Python's interpreter by entering `quit()` Then enter `python -m pip install numpy` in your terminal session and it should work well now.